# How can I get data from a JSON XHR request to use in my template?

Tags: javascript, json, ember.js, xmlhttprequest

I'm very new to ember, and right now I simply want to call an api that generates random text, and have that text display on a page.  The API and specific enpoint I'm using is "http://www.randomtext.me/api/lorem/ul-5/5-15" which returns a JSON response.

app/controllers/randomtext.js

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Controller.extend({
  ajax: Ember.inject.service(),
  actions: {
    sendRequest() {
      return this.get('ajax').request('http://www.randomtext.me/api/lorem/ul-5/5-15');
    }
  }
});
```

This is making the XHR request, and returning the correct JSON object. I can see it in the chrome developer tab.

This is my app/templates/randomtext.hbs

```
 <h1>Random Text</h1>

 <p>test</p><button {{action "sendRequest"}}>testing</button>
```

Pressing the button makes the xhr request, which is solid, but I have no idea how to get the text_out property of the json response, or display any part of it.  How can I (simple as possible) make a GET request to an external api endpoint, and display the response on a page in my ember app?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are returning from within your action handler; but this does not render anything to the screen. You need to make a binding from your template to the javascript file. Please see the following [twiddle](https://ember-twiddle.com/b7163b9567515542e478b936a605c9d7?openFiles=templates.application.hbs%2C). I declared `{{randomText}}` within `application.hbs`. This binds to `randomText` attribute within `application.js` controller. Initially it is undefined; hence no text is rendered. When you press the button; action handler within `application.js` runs. In the action handler; the data returned from remote call is set to the `randomText` attribute with `Ember.String.htmlSafe` function (which formats the returned string as html). You can directly bind attributes declared within `controller` to the corresponding `template`. If you use `route` instead of `controller`; you must make use of `model` hook. I highly recommend you to look at official [Ember Guide](https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.12.0/) and walk through tutorial over there.

Comment: Thank you! works perfectly for what I need it to do!

Answer (score 1):

You need to make request in `app/routes/randomtext.js` inside model hook.

```
model: function() {
 Em.RSVP.Promise.cast(Em.$.getJSON('http://www.randomtext.me/api/lorem/ul-5/5-15')).then((function(_this) {
      return function(data) {
    return Em.Object.create(data);
  };
})(this));
}

setupController: function(controller, model) {
  this._super(controller, model);
 return controller.set('textData', model);
}
```

After that in `app/templates/randomtext.hbs`

You can use `{{#each textData as someText}} <li>This is first item in array {{someText.item}}</li> {{/each}}` helper to loop over array or if response is simple object, and you just want to display some object property, do this `{{textData.title}}` ...